# IE nextSibling and nextElementSibling not working

Tags: javascript

It's just a simple dropdown menu...works fine in Chrome, FF and Safari.
but in IE: **Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null reference**

```js
document.getElementById('icon').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var a = document.getElementsByClassName('menuBookAction');
  for(var i=0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if(a != this) {
      a[i].style.display='none'
    }
  }
  if(this.nextSibling.nextElementSibling.style.display=='none') {
    this.nextSibling.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'block';
  }
});
```

```css
@import 'https://cdn.materialdesignicons.com/1.1.34/css/materialdesignicons.min.css';
#icon { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<div id="icon">
  <i class="mdi mdi-settings"></i>
  <i class="mdi mdi-arrow-drop-down"></i>
</div>
<div class="menuBookAction">
  <div (click)="cancelBooking(b.id);"><i class="mdi mdi-cancel"></i> Cancel Request</div>
</div>
```

Any clue how to make this work in IE as well ? tyvm ! (Raw JS only - no jQuery)

Comment: why you not use just _nextElementSibling_ instead _nextSibling.nextElementSibling_?

Comment: @Grundy, you are right...now it's works. Plz create an "answer" for this so I can set you as the correct answer and upvote you. tyvm !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You not need manually go over text siblings, when you use [`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling) text nodes skiped automatically, so you just need use `nextElementSibling` instead `nextSibling.nextElementSibling`

```js
document.getElementById('icon').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var a = document.getElementsByClassName('menuBookAction');
  for(var i=0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if(a != this) {
      a[i].style.display='none'
    }
  }
  if(this.nextElementSibling.style.display=='none') {
    this.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'block';
  }
});
```

```css
@import 'https://cdn.materialdesignicons.com/1.1.34/css/materialdesignicons.min.css';
#icon { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<div id="icon">
  <i class="mdi mdi-settings"></i>
  <i class="mdi mdi-arrow-drop-down"></i>
</div>
<div class="menuBookAction">
  <div (click)="cancelBooking(b.id);"><i class="mdi mdi-cancel"></i> Cancel Request</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

IE does not support `nextElementSibling` on text nodes, only on elements.

Either polyfill it or only use `nextSibling`.

Answer (score 0):

`nextElementSibling` is not supported in IE according to this MDN page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling

The same page has a Polyfill, and that could be a solution if you don't want to avoid using `nextElementSibling`.

```
if(!("nextElementSibling" in document.documentElement)){
    Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype, "nextElementSibling", {
        get: function(){
            var e = this.nextSibling;
            while(e && 1 !== e.nodeType)
                e = e.nextSibling;
            return e;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: not supported on [_CharacterData_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CharacterData)